# Неверно отображаются значения C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите новичку в С# что не так, пожалуйста. Есть форма, в которой заполняются поля 17-значными числами. В БД sqlite тип данных BigInt, туда они пишутся правильно, а при отображении в ListView в программе числа другие.
Ниже строка с преобразованием введенной строки в Int64. Я так понимаю, BigInt в C# == Int64

```
...
Row[db.FootwearPrint.aN_Card_old] = Convert.ToInt64(ed_N_Card_old.Text);
...
```

[image: скрин из БД]

[image: скрин из проги]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]я думаю вы скорее всего не правильно получаете значения из базы или заполняете форму не теми значениями ed_N_Card_old.Text (string) содержит нужное значение перед тем как вы его конвертируете в INT64 ?